# Qual a forma correta de utilizar o header location?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Estou fazendo um curso de PHP e MySQL no Alura e chegou na parte onde construímos o código que remove o produto do banco de dados.

A página que chama a função de deletar tem de redirecionar o usuário novamente para a página `produto-lista.php` e o instrutor do curso sugeriu o seguinte código:

```
<?php
  include("cabecalho.php");
  include("conecta.php");
  include("banco-produto.php");

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  removeProduto($conexao, $id);
  header["location: produto-lista.php"];
?>
```

Acontece que dessa maneira o produto está sim sendo removido porém o `header location` está me gerando o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant header - assumed 'header' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\remove-produto.php on line 8
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'location: produto-lista.php' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\remove-produto.php on line 8

Estou usando Xamp para Windows.

Comment: Dê sempre uma lida no [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) para usar funções que não conhece. Agora, o que MUITA gente esquece, é que praticamente sempre, depois de um header location você sempre precisa de um exit() ou die() se tiver mais código na página, e o header for condicional. No seu caso, se não tiver mais nada na página, o exit não vai fazer diferença. Mas é importante saber que se ele não existir, o cliente receberá as informações todas antes de redirecionar.

Comment: Outro problema que vejo constantemente com soluções iguais a essa são os avisos `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...`, pois, provavelmente este `cabecalho.php` está gerando códigos HTML que já gerou um `header` e você tenta modificá-lo.

Comment: @RenoirDosReis totalmente alheia a pergunta: o curso da Alura é bom?

Comment: Oi @Bia, estou gostando bastante dos cursos do Alura e já estou conseguindo desenvolver coisas interessantes com pouco menos de uma semana de imersão total no mesmo, abraços!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No lugar de `header["location: produto-lista.php"];` coloca `header("location: produto-lista.php"); die('Não ignore meu cabeçalho...');`

O `die()` é importante para que nada seja executado após esse comando, assim evitando algum erro inesperado, poderia usar `exit()` também.

Answer (score 7):

O erro que se encontra no código que você postou na questão está na forma como você está chamando a função header, onde ao invés de usar parênteses você está usando colchetes.

Forma errada:

```
header["location: produto-lista.php"];
```

Forma correta:

```
header("location: produto-lista.php");
```

Obs.: Lembrando também que a função header tem que ser sempre usada antes de qualquer output de dados enviado, pois ela manipula o cabeçalho da requisição HTTP enviada.

Comment: +1 Pela observação. É comum o `header` não funcionar por já ter sido enviado alguma coisa antes.